# How to show Interstitial once in ios app?

Tags: ios, interstitial

Every time I open category the Interstitial appears I want to make it appears once

the code

```
//----------Interstitial Initialization-------------//
-(void)createAndLoadInterstitial
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    _interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:appDelegate.InterstitialAdUnitID];
    _interstitial.delegate = self;
    [_interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
{
    [_interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
{
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidDismissScreen");
}
```

Comment: you need to initialise in viewDidLoad . because  GADInterstitial is a one time use object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
//call your method here
     [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
    });
```

Comment: I'm amateur should I put this before the code? right

Comment: where are you calling this method createAndLoadInterstitial

Comment: in the same file

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(createAndLoadInterstitial) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    
    singleton = [[Singleton ShareInstance] init];
    
    lblcatname.text = singleton.catname;

Comment: comment first line and check once, you want to load only once right?

Comment: I tried this time, it appears once but when I trying to open another categories it show no content and no ads

Comment: What do you want do achieve? the above code run only once until your app terminate.

Comment: it appears every time I open category it so disturbing

Comment: did you comment this line  
[self performSelector:@selector(createAndLoadInterstitial) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

Comment: then add above code, your code is too long, try to reduce your code and  learn Auto Layout feature for device compatibility